# Working with derived classes as JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3 to generate my database from some classes.  I have an `Item` class which has a collection of `Deals` that can be either free or discounted.  My classes are modeled like so:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Other properties
    public virtual ICollection<Deal> Deals { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Deal
{        
    //These properties are shared between various Deals
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Monday { get; set; }
    public bool Tuesday { get; set; }
    public bool Wednesday { get; set; }
    public bool Thursday { get; set; }
    public bool Friday { get; set; }
    public bool Saturday { get; set; }
    public bool Sunday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeFrom { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeTo { get; set; }
    public int AgesFrom { get; set; }
    public int AgesTo { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; } 
}
public class DiscountedDeal : Deal
{
    public double PriceAfterDiscount { get; set; }
}
public class FreeDeal : Deal
{
    //No properties needed here
}
```

Then in my `onModelCreating`

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<FreeDeal>().ToTable("FreeDeals");
        modelBuilder.Entity<DiscountedDeal>().ToTable("DiscountedDeals");
    }
```

I originally had a single `Deal` class with a boolean field to denote if it was free or not.  The way I have it now seems a bit more normalized but naturally makes things more complicated.

At the front end I'm using ajax calls to send and retrieve this data but I'm not sure how treat the separate deals.  If I retrieve an `Item` and it has 3 `Deals`, say 2 `Free` and 1 `Discounted` how can I deal with that?  Should I have 2 `Collections` (1 for `Free` and 1 for `Discounted`) in my item class?  Should I so go back to having one `Deal` class with a flag?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the requirements, I would suggest changing the your model so that deals and and items live at the same level and you can simply apply deals to different items. As it is now you would have to create a seperate deal for every item if say you wanted to give a fifteen percent discount to items on wednesdays.

Also, I think that having a price set on the deal is a bad idea if you're letting an item have multiple deals... That forces you to have logic that determines the order of deal precedence etc. If keeping the database normailized is what you're after you I would go back to the single deal class and just give it a DealType which would be another class so that a DealTypes table is created. You could then keep the child classes and instead of having them hold the price you could give them and ApplyDeal method that would apply the deal to the item price.